# InstallShield running Setup.rul actions outside IS installation?

Tags: deployment, installshield

As far as I understand it, all `Setup.rul` and include script file actions are being marked with f1, f2 - f99 .... references, and are being called using `issetup.dll` (I assume they are stored inside). The question is: how can I properly run those functions using `issetup.dll` (and `rundll32`?) outside of the installer project installation? If it is possible at all.

Comment: You probably have to contact Installshield technical support for this level of "inside knowledge", but I really don't think they would let you know (as long as Installscript is proprietary). Can we ask what the requirements for this are and why it is necessary? I will throw in a link to installsite.org's discussion forum: [forum.installsite.net](https://forum.installsite.net/) and [Installshield's own forum](https://community.flexerasoftware.com).

Comment: We use InstallShield for windows installers and IS Universal (which is extremely old) for *nix platforms. Right now we investigate possibility of moving to shell-based kind of deployment in order to be compatible with Docker and to be able to support various platforms and also split it into smaller pieces. Possibility to re-use would probably make it easier and to keep both installers (old and shell-based) consistent while migrating

Answer (score 0):

The code and supporting bits of ISSetup.dll are self-contained when built with InstallShield 12 or later. However the `f##` entry points follow the format of all Windows Installer [type 1 custom actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368075) and require an actual `MSIHANDLE hInstaller` to be passed to them. Even if you aren't leveraging [Windows Installer API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369426) in your code, the initialization that takes place between calling the `f##` function and invoking your InstallScript function will access the handle, and will probably malfunction if called with an invalid handle value. Feel free to try it, and if it works and you don't have to support it externally, it might even be "safe enough."

If you are attempting to use the InstallScript scripting language for purposes other than installation, while it's not exactly supported territory, it's possible to create an InstallScript project, and replace the normal event-driven code with a `program ... endprogram` block. This creates a procedural script, and, unless you include it, will avoid most of the logic specific to installation. So this may give you the behavior you are looking for, but it will still look like an Installer from the outside. (While InstallScript is general purpose in theory, the only practical implementations are very tied to installation.) Note that you'll have a hard time getting support from the vendor or from most other programmers if you go this route.